# Fairy Lights Wiring

Tags: wiring, lighting

I am working on making a costume that will require the use of fairy lights also known as string lights. It requires 16 separate strings and each string has its own small battery pack which contains 2 cr2032 3v batteries and a on/off switch. So a total of 32 cr2032 3v batteries

[These](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077KB6T94) are the lights I purchased.

So for testing purposes I tested this with 4 fairy lights and 1 9V battery. Note I have tried wiring 2 strings to 2 AAs and the brightness was not there. Not to mention having to carry around 32 AAs would be a bit tedious. Attached is an image of how I wired it up in series and parallel. [image: wiring]

1. Series wiring - LEDs would not light up
2. Parallel wiring - LEDs would light up however the battery slowly started getting hotter and hotter.

My question is, what would be the easiest way to wire all of these into 1 switch safely. Please keep in mind that this will be part of a costume so I'd like to keep weight down to a minimum. Note that carrying 4 9V batteries is alot ligher than 32AAs. I'm just not sure how I would wire them. And if resistors are needed, what size and where would they be inserted?

New Image wiring:

[image: New Image]

Comment: Note that both button cells and 9v batteries have poor energy density and high cost, so they should be used only when form factor makes them necessary.  AAs have such higher energy density that you likely can use smaller mass, add a voltage converter and pay it's losses, and still come out on top.

Comment: As a compromise, you may wish to consider "fake" AAs and 9vs.  There are AAAs, AAs and 9V batteries available now that actually have a 3.7V li-ion cell and a voltage converter inside them, giving much higher performance than an actual alkaline 9v.  These batteries include a microusb input for charging them.

Comment: a 9V batttery contains six 1.5V AAAA cells .... way less power than AA or even AAA cells

Answer (score 2):

In the second one, the switch is shorting the battery through the path highlighted in blue, so it gets hot.

[image]

Correct wiring: the fairy lights are in parallel, but the battery and switch have to be in series.

[image]

If the fairy lights work on 3-4V they're probably white LEDs all wired in parallel, you will need resistors (blue):

[image]

It is preferable to use one resistor per string, that will make the brightness more even and the resistor will heat less. No idea what value you need, to know that you'd need to know how much current the lights use. If they used CR2032 batteries, these have quite high internal resistance, so you can start with 100 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd is correct, all LEDs in parallel. Two CR2032 make 6V. Use a 4AA battery pack to drive the LEDs.  Put the switch in series between the battery+ and the LED+.

Comment: Thanks for the info about wiring them in parallel. In regards of the batteries, I am using 16 strings, which with your reply I would need 64 AA batteries which is a bit much to carry. What other options do I have? Also noted, while wired in parallel with the 9v battery and 4 strings the battery started getting hotter which is kind of a concern.

Comment: I think the battery got hot because you either shorted it out with the switch (which your 2nd drawing shows), or were drawing too much current from the battery.The lights only want 6V, not 9V. One 4xAA pack should be fine, or one 4xC on one 4xD if you want longer on time.

Comment: Just one battery pack for all the light strips in parallel.

Comment: You are right about the switch wiring. I just changed it to per your suggestion and its good.

Comment: So what you are saying in regards of the battery, if I were to use 4xD sized batteries I will be able to power all 16 strings? If so would it be any difference if I were to use 8xAA since I already have a holder?

Comment: 4 will yield 6V.   8 will yield 12V and damage all the strings.

Comment: So I received the 4 AA battery pack that has a built in switch so I do not need a separate switch that I originally had in the diagram. My question is, when hooking up the battery pack with the build in switch, Do I wire connect it as parallel as well? Meaning do I connect all the positives together including the pack and all the negatives together including the pack?

Comment: Yes. The switch should then connect the battery+ to the LED+.

Comment: The switch is built into the battery case itself.

Comment: I figured out the switch and wiring situation however the batteries do not seem to be lasting at all. I have some 1900 MAH AA rechargeable batteries and the brightness cuts in half in less than an hour. Anyway to make these last longer? If I switch them to 4xD batteries will there be a significant difference in terms of lasting time?

Comment: Alkaline D-cells, with 12000-18000 mAh capacity, would last quite a while longer.  Alkaline C-cells have up to 8000 mAH capacity  and would last quite a while too. Or NiMH C-cells, rechargeable, 6000mAH capacity.

Comment: So while I'm waiting on the D size battery pack holder to arrive I decided to try using 4x AA Energizer Lithium batteries. These seem to be lasting much longer, however the batteries tend to get very hot where as the alkalines did not. I have added a new image of my wiring with the Lithium batteries, is there something wrong with my wiring or are lithium batteries not recommended for this? How can I prevent these batteries from over heating?

Comment: 3000mAH capacity, not seeing what current flow they are intended for, but probably not as much as you are drawing if they are getting hot.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused as to your reply. Since you've recommended D cells with higher mAh how would these lithium batteries be any different? I am desperate to get this working so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery  "Energizer brand rates its alkaline D cell at approximately 20,000mAh at 25mA draw, but estimates performance closer to about 10,000mAh at 500mA draw."   Lithium AA http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/lithiuml91l92_appman.pdf   Page 7 "In low to moderate drain applications, less than 500 mA, the heat dissipates and should not activate the PTC. " If it is not shutting itself off, I suspect it is not overheating, while warm.  Do you have a multimeter? Put it in current mode, in series with the + line, see how much current you are drawing with the lights.

Comment: So I decided to give something a try and installed a resister inline with 4 strings hooked up to a 4x AA battery pack. And although they aren't as bright, they are bright enough and have lasted 12 hours so far with no heat issues. I think I'm going to stick with this route or maybe test with 8 strings and 4x D batteries when I get the holder. Thank you for all your help crossroads

Comment: Glad you found a solution you liked.

Comment: Of course you need a resistor. The CR2032 batteries are so small that they produce a low maximum current like a more powerful battery that has a series resistor. Two series CR2032 batteries produce 6V only when new and with no load. their voltage drops when they have a load, measure it with a new string of fairly lights and new CR2032 batteries. The sales sheet says each bulb is 4V.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider. Led fairy lights typically have all the leds in parallel.

1, cr2032 have high internal resistance. As the current draw gets higher, the voltage drops. If your fairy lights do not have a resistor, it may rely on that internal resistance to keep the voltage and current in check. AA batteries do not have this high resistance so that may not be good for your leds. Whatever voltage you get, use ohms law for the resistor you need. (Source Voltage - measured voltage) / Current = Resistance. See below for current.

2, how long do you want the batteries to last?  And how much current does each string pull? If you measure the current, say the string pulls 80mA. Then you have 16 strings, that's 1280 mA. With standard good energizer Alkaline AA with a capacity of 2800mAh, that's roughly 2.25 Hours of run time. Let's round to 2 hours of good brightness. If the current is only 40mA then that's 4 hours. Etc.

So first you need to know the voltage across the led string with the cr2032. Maybe it gets pulled down because of the current. And you need to know the current draw. Both are easy to find with a multimeter.

Having known both, I recommend either 3x AA for 4.5V or a usb power bank at 5V. Use a 1n4001 diode to bring the voltage down 0.7V for safety. Then add calculate the formula. For a 5V usb power bank, minus 0.7V for the diode, (4.3V - 3.5V measured voltage) / (0.08 A current per string * 16 Strings) ~= 1 Ohm resistor.